# How to modify a gradle file to run Make in a NDK directory?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, makefile, android-ndk, task

I have an Android app that I need to link in SWIG-generated native code. The Makefile is able to run SWIG, install the generated Java files, and create the *.so. Currently, we have to go into the native code directory and run 'make' by hand then store the generated Java in our RCS, a really bad idea.

I learned that I can create a task(){} in Gradle that will run and external task, like 'make'. This is what I have:

```
task buildSwig(type: Exec) {
    workingDir './app/src/main/cpp'
    commandLine 'make', 'distclean', 'swig', 'c++'
}
```

I placed it in 'build.gradle' thus:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.3'
        classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.3.1'
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://clojars.org/repo/"
        }
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    }
}

project.ext.preDexLibs = !project.hasProperty('disablePreDex')

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

task buildSwig(type: Exec) {
    workingDir './app/src/main/cpp'
    commandLine 'make', 'distclean', 'swig', 'c++'
}
```

which a modified, standard generated Gradle file. The questions I have are: 1) how do I hook in the 'buildSwig' task into the build itself? and 2) am I using the correct Gradle script? It appears that the task is being ignored. Naturally, the Makefile must be run before everything else.

Also, once this problem is corrected, will the generated Java files be recognized by the Gradle build processes?

Answer (score 0):

In your application `build.gradle`, you can make tasks with `JavaCompile` type depend on your `buildSwig` task :

```
android {

    ......
    ......

    task buildSwig(type: Exec, description: 'Compile source') {
        commandLine 'make', '-C', file('src/main/cpp').absolutePath, 'distclean', 'swig', 'c++'
    }

    task cleanSwig(type: Exec, description: 'Clean object files') {
        commandLine 'make', '-C', file('src/main/cpp').absolutePath, 'distclean'
    }

    clean.dependsOn 'cleanSwig'

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask - > compileTask.dependsOn buildSwig
    }
}
```